# JPA Criteria Builder create predicates with open ended date-range

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to query for my entities - with JPA criteria builder, based on a specified date range. For instance, given a from-date and a to-date, I'd like to retrieve my entities where their startDate and endDate fall within the specified range given by the predicate.

Here is a snippet of my code using a Specification where the predicates will be constructed

```
...
    public static Specification<Transaction> enquirySpecification(Dto dto) {
        return new Specification<Transaction>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Transaction> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
                ...
                if (dto.getFromDate() != null && dto.getToDate() != null) {
                    ZonedDateTime fromDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dto.getFromDate(), LocalTime.MIN, ZonedDateTime.now().getZone());
                    ZonedDateTime toDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dto.getToDate(), LocalTime.MAX, ZonedDateTime.now().getZone());
                    Expression<ZonedDateTime> createdDateTime = root.get("milestones").get("startTime");
                    Predicate fromToDatePredicate = cb.between(createdDateTime, fromDateTime, toDateTime);
                    predicates.add(fromToDatePredicate);
                }
                else if (dto.getFromDate() != null && dto.getToDate() == null) {
                    ZonedDateTime fromDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dto.getFromDate(), LocalTime.MIN, ZonedDateTime.now().getZone());
                    Predicate fromDatePredicate = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("milestones").get("startTime"), fromDateTime);
                    predicates.add(fromDatePredicate);
                }
                else if (dto.getToDate() != null && dto.getFromDate() == null) {
                    ZonedDateTime toDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dto.getToDate(), LocalTime.MAX, ZonedDateTime.now().getZone());
                    Predicate toDatePredicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("milestones").get("endTime"), toDateTime);
                    predicates.add(toDatePredicate);
                }
                ...
...
```

When I specify a from-date and a to-date, I'm able to get all my entities within that specified date range. And when I specify only a from-date and leave my to-date as null, I'm able to get all my entities starting from the specified from-date.
However, when I leave my from-date as null and only specify a to-date, I'm unable to retrieve any of my entities (in this case, I'm trying to get all entities up to the specified to-date regardless of what their from-dates are).

How can I construct a predicate where I can retrieve all my entities up to the specified to-date? Should I be using `.lessThanOrEqualTo()`?

Comment: Your code looks ok but there are a couple of questions: you're only using `"endTime"` in the predicate that doesn't work - does that attribute exist and does it have exactly that name? Do the entities have an end date that is less or equal to the end of the range? Also, your description and code don't match, i.e. you're only checking the entities' start date is in the range if it is closed but your description states the end date should also be in the range. Could you provide some examples of what you'd expect to get?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the prompt response and for taking the time to look through my code. I realized that I wasn't getting anything because my entities in the database had null for the "endTime" attribute so I wasnt getting anything for my queries. Apologies!